# Issue with Rails query joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, relationship

I have a really dumb issue, I have two models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role
end
```

and

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user
end
```

I'm trying to get the user and make a join with the role's table to get the role's name and id, like:

"user" : {
"name": "json",
"role": {"name":"admin", "id":1}
}

however, after using:

```
User.includes(:role).all
```

I just get the users with a "role_id" value, I've also tried:

```
User.joins(:role)
```

With the same result. I've been looking at the official docs at (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and it should be pretty straightforward but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Do I need to add something to my migrations?, At my create_user migration I have:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.integer :role_id
    end

    add_index :users, :email 
    add_index :users, :username
  end
end
```

and my create_roles migration

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you are literally wanting the JSON output, then the posted answer is the way to go. If you just want access to the attributes, you would use `User.includes(:role).each { |user| ... }` and inside the block you have access to `user.name`, `user.role.id`, and `user.role.name`.

Comment: Both worked and are useful, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all) by itself doesn't return such a custom data. You can use [`as_json`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) for that:

```
User.all.as_json(only: :name, include: { role: { only: [:name, :id] } }, root: true)
# User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
# Role Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
# => [{"user"=>{"name"=>"json", "role"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"admin"}}}]
```